# Why does Ajax reset my window scroll position to zero?

Tags: jquery, scroll

In [my page](http://46.20.119.207/~asuntosf/1234/) I have a header DIV, a link and a target DIV. The link loads - through jQuery load() - a picture in the target DIV.

Problem : if you scroll a bit down AND THEN click on the link, you'll see that the window scroll position resets to zero. Yet it's an Ajax event, the scroll position should remain exactly the same !

Note that this is true only the first time you click. If you reload the page and click again, the picture will load without scroll position changing (normal behaviour). You have to clean your browser cache if you want to replicate the problem again.

Any idea of what's going on here ?

Comment: please post code and demos for future generations. Your link might get down after some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your target div changes it's size depending on its child.

If for example you set the height of your `target` to `866px` (the height of the image) and set the height of your child div to something smaller (at the moment its `1000px`), you shouldn't experience these problems (at least I don't have this problem anymore under Chrome)

Comment: But why scroll position reset fails to occur if you click again after page reload (F5) ?

Comment: It still does occur depending on the circumstances. It's because when you reload, it remembers the position as its initial state. Try scrolling back up before reloading, then try to recreate that problem - it will still happen.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple...you have a div inside target with inline height = 1500px. You are replacing that with ajax so body is shrinking as new content isn't same height

Comment: If this was the cause of the problem, then the problem should occur everytime you click on the link. Yet, it occurs only the first time. Reload the page and click again : it won't occur (picture will replace the 1500px without scroll position reset)